# Site Specific search query

Tags: search, search-results, query

I want to create a query for a search results that is the same as the default one, in that it only returns things in the particular section of the site it is in.
Does anyone know what this query would be if I was to create it myself? I'm using SP2013, I have tried using `Path:{Site.URL}` when in Snippet Gallery but that uses the site that my results page is in

Comment: SP2010 or SP2013?

Comment: it is for SP2013

Answer (score 0):

The standard query for everything is (w/o people results) is:

```
{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople}
```

So if you want a "this site only" scope you should add the url as filter either with

```
path:"http://hostname.fqdn/sites/site1"
```

or with a Query Variable

```
path:"{site.url}"
```

You can see the substitutions in the query builder wizard in the "TEST" tab.

Comment: What if I am using this page for multiple sites? as site.url will only do it for the page the search results is on

Comment: add multiple path properties: path:http://hostname.fqdn/sites/site1 path:http://hostname.fqdn/sites/site2 ... SharePoint will OR-join the results.

Comment: I only want it to search the site I am in. so say I have to site hi and bye. When I use the search for hi it only return things in hi and the same for bye